# Using Rake to submit a Cucumber test in Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, rake

I seem to be having some issues with Rake and my Cucumber features file.

Here is the command in Jenkins. It specifys the Rake file that I have put directly in the ./features directory so the testjson.feature is right there.

```
/usr/local/bin/rake --rakefile /home/robm/code/BDD/practise-tests/testtq/features/Rakefile
```

Rakefile looks like this:

```
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new :features do |t|
 t.cucumber_opts = '*.feature'
end
```

It's pretty straightforward but in the console output from Jenkins I get:

```
 Feature: Validate DUT JSON
    JSON should be evaluated for all routes in API
    All API routes should return valid JSON
    If JSON is invalid for one or more route in API it has DUT failed

  Scenario Outline: Validate JSON                             # testJson.feature:6
    Given there is a DUT with "<input>" and "<un>" and "<pw>" # testJson.feature:7
    When the JsonTest code is run                             # testJson.feature:8
    Then the output should be "<output>"                      # testJson.feature:9

    Examples: 
      | input           | un    | pw         | output |
      | 172.168.101.139 | username | password | CHECK  |
      | 172.168.101.214 | username | password | CHECK  |

2 scenarios (2 undefined)
6 steps (6 undefined)
0m0.007s
```

which tells me it's not finding the feature file, right?

When I go to the directory above the feature file and run Cucumber the test works!

So, obviously I have an error with my Rake file. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO supports a number of formatting options for questions and answers that make it much easier for us to read what you've written. See [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I put this in as my Rake working directory
/home/robm/code/BDD/practise-tests/testtq

then specified the feature file

"./features/testJson.feature"

that got it to work not sure why the other didn't work.